# NetworkOnmainThreadException android+Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have code that does write byte stream into a file and return the file
but I am getting networkonmainthreadexception on writing input stream to file

```
accessTokenValidationWithResponseBodyForPDF(LinkApi.downloadFile(fileUrl))
                .flatMap(new Function<ResponseBody, ObservableSource<File>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<File> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.just(writeResponseBodyToDisk(responseBody))
                                .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, File>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public File apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                        return new File(AppConstants.not_valid);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NotNull File resultObject) {
                        try {
                            hideProgress();
                            if (resultObject.getPath().equals(AppConstants.not_valid)) {

                                showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong), true);

                            } else {

                                File pdfFile = (File) resultObject;
                                downloadedFile = pdfFile;
                                if (pdfFile != null) {
                                    displayPdf(pdfFile);
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        hideProgress();
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

```
     private File writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {

        
        String extStorageDirectory = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();

        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, ".Link");
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdir();

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        int random = secureRandom.nextInt();

        File futureStudioIconFile = new File(extStorageDirectory + File.separator + ".Link" + File.separator + "link" + random + ".pdf");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);//going to exception with networkonmainthreadexception

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

            }

//                outputStream.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("PDF", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            safeClose(inputStream);
            safeClose(outputStream);
        }


        return futureStudioIconFile;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you call `writeResponseBodyToDisk` then turn its result, into an Observable. You have to make the method call itself happen on a background thread, for example via

```java
Observable.fromCallable(() -> writeResponseBodyToDisk(responseBody))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.onErrorReturn(...)
```

Note that having `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in your original code does not reach into the `flatMap` because the function runs on the emitter thread of `accessTokenValidationWithResponseBodyForPDF`. You have to put `subscribeOn`s as close to the work and often repeat it many times at many places.

Comment: Thanks it worked..really helped your explanation as well since I am learning  rxjava

Comment: I changed like below is it correct?
return Observable.fromCallable(()->writeResponseBodyToDisk(responseBody))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .onErrorReturn({...})
                                });
                    }